Помогите решить задачу. Не знаю как делать перенос времени в SQL при помощи функций с датами
Данные о записях пациентов к врачу хранятся в таблице calendar.
Перенесите на 1,5 часа вперед все записи после 13 часов дня (включительно) за 14 мая 2017 года.
calendar
id  user_id visit_date
1   1   2017-05-13 11:00:00
2   5   2017-05-13 12:00:00
3   145 2017-05-13 15:30:00
4   147 2017-05-14 10:00:00
5   276 2017-05-14 12:00:00
6   18  2017-05-14 13:00:00
7   7   2017-05-14 14:00:00
8   1873    2017-05-14 15:30:00
9   18  2017-05-14 16:30:00
10  147 2017-05-16 11:00:00
11  971 2017-05-16 12:30:00
12  91  2017-05-16 15:30:00
13  1355    2017-06-14 11:00:00
14  987 2017-06-14 12:30:00
15  34  2017-06-14 14:00:00



Можно использовать UPDATE таблицы по условию, в столбце времени с вычислением требуемого значения.
UPDATE table
set visit date = текущее время +1,5 часа
WHERE visit date > 13.00;

Пожалуйста, откорректируйте ваш запрос и сделайте его синтаксически корректным.

а если нужно использовать функции с датами, то что писать? без обновления таблицы

Функции с датами все равно надо использовать для вычисления даты или времени и часа, у вас формат данных datetime я так понимаю. А как кроме обновления таблицы внести данные? можно заменить запись, или старые записи должны остаться? Я вам подсказал направление куда думать. Вы сами пробовали какие-то варианты. Судя по скрину, это какие-то тестовые или курсовые задачки. Для более детального ответа, мне нужно сделать запрос, к сожалению пока не могу, занят.
